# Cambiar color de filas en TableView JavaFX segun su valor

Tags: java, javafx, constructor

Buenos dias!

Al grano tengo una interfaz donde muestro una tabla con dos columnas la primera es Placa y la otra es Kilometraje. 
Lo que quiero hacer es lograr que segun el valor que la columna Kilometraje tenga en su celda su Color de fondo cambie Ejemplo:
**Placa: 0001 Kilometraje: 5000**
Si **Kilometraje** es **mayor o igual a 5000** pintar de color Rojo.
Aqui muestro mi tabla:
[image: Agradezco su ayuda!]
Aqui el codigo que muestra la tabla:

```
 @Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    conexion = new Conexion();
    conexion.establecerConexion();

    informacionAlertas = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Menu.mostrarTablaAlertasMenu(conexion.getConnection(), informacionAlertas);
    tblInformacion.setItems(informacionAlertas);

    clmnAlertaPlaca.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("AlertaPlaca"));
    clmnAlertaKmRest.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("AlertaKmRest"));






}
```

Answer (score 2):

te paso un código de ejemplo que debes adaptar a tu problema pero que creo que te servirá de guía para resolver tu problema:

```
TableColumn<Object, Integer> columna = new TableColumn<>();
columna.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Object,Integer>, TableCell<Object,Integer>>(){
        @Override
        public TableCell<Object, Integer> call(TableColumn<Object, Integer> tablecolumn) {
            return new TableCell<Object,Integer>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (item != null){
                        if (item.intValue() > 5000){
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                        }
                        else if (item.intValue() == 200){
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
                        }
                    }

                }
            };
        }
    });
```

Lo realmente importante es asignarle un CellFactory a tu columna, y a la hora de devolver la TableCell para renderizarse, sobreescribir el updateItem y hacer ahí tu lógica para customizar la celda.

Comment: Gracias lo adaptare a mi codigo haber que tal Saludos